# javascript flashvar question with JW Player

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I don't know if I'll be able to get this answer here, but I'm trying to get the JW Player to toggle between high and low quality settings.  Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject('/lessons/videos/player.swf','mpl','610','480','9');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addVariable('plugins', 'http://www.mbira.me/lessons/videos/plugins/hd/hd.swf');
so.addVariable('hd.state',false);
so.addVariable('hd.autoswitch',false);
so.addVariable('hd.bandwidth',3200);
so.addVariable('hd.file', '/lessons/videos/Buka_Tiende_from_calculator.flv');
so.addVariable('file','/lessons/L2/Nhemamusasa_Acoustic.flv');
so.write('mediaspace');
</script>
```

I read here that there is a setting that there is a default built into the HD plugin to switch determined on the users bandwidth.  I downloaded a patch here:
http://interfacelab.com/patch-for-hd-plugin-for-jw-player/

So I could disable that behavior to test, but still no luck.  You can see in my code, that for now, I just have two different videos to toggle in order to test if things are working.  I should say that both those videos are actually "high quality" for now, but that shouldn't make a difference I guess.  Any ideas, and if not, any other places I could look to implement this functionality?
Thanks!
Joel

Comment: The only other place that comes to mind is the JW Player support forum :)

Comment: Yes-I've tried there, and as usual-I need to try and get this taken care of right away.

Comment: Do you even know that such functionality exists in JW player itself? Or are you using the HD plugin?

Comment: And what exactly is your problem, that the switch doesn't work or that it does work?

Comment: I'm using the HD plugin and it isn't working.  It is not switching videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
so.addVariable('plugins', 'plugins=hd-1');
```

needs to be changed to:

```
so.addVariable('plugins', 'hd-1');
```

The example page was incorrect...